# functional equation:$f(f(x))=6x-f(x)$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> Prove that there exists a unique function  $f:R^{+}\rightarrow R^{+}$ $$f(f(x))=6x-f(x)$$

**My Try**

Define $a_{k+1}=f(a_k)$ then we have  the recursive relation $$a_{k+2}+a_{k+1}-6a_k=0$$ whose  characteristic equation is $$x^{k+2}+x^{k+1}-6x^k=0$$ $$x^2+x-6=0 \Rightarrow x=-3 ,x=2$$ ie $$a_k=c_1 {(-3)}^k+c_2{(2)}^k$$ .As $x>0 \Rightarrow a_0>0\Rightarrow 2c_2>3c_1$

i am  stuck now as i have not been able to find $c_1,c_2$

Comment: If we guess that $f$ is linear, then we find that $f(x) = 2x$ is the only possible solution.

Comment: @Adriano nice!that means we are left to prove no other function exists

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h156809p879769

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Too bad that neither the answer on MSE or the answers on Art of Problem Solving link prove the unicity. TBH I have no idea how to prove unicity

Comment: @Raffaele yes i noticed that,its a problem from putnam so i guess it has to be very diffcult thank you for your interest though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After OP's work:** For $a_{k+2}+a_{k+1}-6a_k=0$, take $a_k=t^k$ to get $t_{1,2}=2,-3$.
Choose only positive root to write $a_k=C 2^k \implies a_0=C=x$ (by assumption), next $a_1=C. 2=2x$. By assumption $f(x)=a_1.$ So you get $f(x)=2x.$

Note: here $$a_0=x, a_1=f(x),a_2=ff(x), a_3=fff(x),....,a_k=f^{k}(x).$$

Comment: It's not "choose only positive root", that's not a valid assumption. It's that: If $ a_k = A2^k + B(-3)^k$ with $ B \neq 0$, then we can find a large enough $k$ such that $ a_k < 0$ contradicting the assumption that $f: R^+ \rightarrow R^+$, hence $B=0$.

Comment: @CalvinLin  i understand it now,it was a bit difficult to understand the OP's idea at first.Thanks to you!